# Typescript error and I can't assign a function to a RefObject.current AND it says its not callable

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Anyone know why I can't assign a function type to a ref.current type?

```
  useEffect(() => {
    savedHandler.current = handler; // ERROR HERE:
  }, [handler]);
```

> TS2741: Property 'current' is missing in type '(e: ChangeEvent) => any' but required in type
> 'RefObject'.

later on I then try to call that function and get an error:

```
   const eventListener = (event: Event) => savedHandler?.current?.(event);
```

which gives me the error:

> TS2349: This expression is not callable.   Type
> 'RefObject' has no call signatures.

If I can assign a function to current then I should be able to call it, no?
But, why is it complainging that I can't assign a function to "current". The code works fine, just those TS errors are driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's a problem with `savedHandler` type. This works for me:

```js
function useInterval(callback: () => void) {
  const savedCallback = useRef<typeof callback>();

  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);
}
```